# jQuery click fires multiple times inside click function

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-ui-accordion

I added code excerpts to this link http://jsfiddle.net/rUbD8/1/

I created the following 3 accordion sliders in the result part of jsfiddle on the name your slider:
**Home**,  **About** and **Contact**

When I click the *Delete It* button on the Home slider it writes to the console.log 3 times
then when I click *Delete It* on the About slider it writes to the console.log 2 times

Can someone tell me why its doing that and how to prevent it from firing multiple times?

Answer (score 3):

It's because each time you add a slider the click function is bound to the element with 'deleteMe' class you can try

```
jQuery('.deleteMe').unbind('click').click(function(e){}) ...
```

as a quick fix

Answer (score 1):

It is doing it because you are wiring up the event each time you add a new element.

To resolve, move the click event handler out of where it is, using a live event handler (monitors for new items):

http://jsfiddle.net/rUbD8/3/

```
jQuery('.slider_holder').on('click', '.deleteMe', function(e) {
    header = jQuery(e.target).parent().prev();
    container = jQuery(e.target).parent();

    console.log(e.target);

    header.fadeOut('slow',function(){
        jQuery(this).remove();
    });
    container.slideUp('normal',function(){
        jQuery(this).remove();
    });
});
```